# How do I decode a string with utf-8?

Tags: python, string, utf-8

I have a string that is already encoded with utf-8 (ex. "No\xf0\x9f\x92\x80"). I would like to decode it so it becomes No. However, when I use .decode('utf-8) it says decode is not a function of a str.

The string is from a txt file that I am reading with pandas.

Comment: Are you using Python3?

Comment: You can *decode* `bytes` to `str`, and *encode* `str` to `bytes`. If you already have a string, you are done.

Comment: Read the file with the correct encoding in the first place.  The default wasn't UTF-8.

Comment: I am using python3. The string is exactly "No\xf0\x9f\x92\x80" so if I decode it to bytes it turns into b"No\\xf0\\x9f\\x92\\x80" instead of No

Comment: I am using: df = pd.read_csv('gpt2_gentext_20200915_223526.txt', encoding="utf-8", 
                 delimiter = "====================", index_col=False, 
               names=['Tweet'], engine='python')

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What exactly is in the string?  Is the length of `No\xF0\x9f\x92\x80` six or eighteen?

Comment: So is the answer to my question 6 or 18?  It sounds like it is 18, but your syntax is vague.  If typed as you typed it, the first is length 6, and the second is a syntax error.  Put the value in a string `s` and `print(ascii(s))`.  Cut and paste the result into your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. len() returns 6

Comment: string = 'No\xf0\x9f\x92\x80'
print(len(string))
print(ascii(string)) returns 6 and 'No\xf0\x9f\x92\x80'

Comment: So how did you get `b"No\\xf0\\x9f\\x92\\x80"`?

Comment: from encoding it with utf-8                                                                                              
for i in range(16):
    tweet = df.iloc[i]['Tweet']
    print(tweet.encode('utf-8'))

Comment: @jugwo please update your question with the information you provided in the comments, so it will be more clear to others what you are looking for. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the length is 6, that doesn't quite make sense if you read the file with `encoding='utf8'`.  It should have decoded the UTF-8 bytes correctly, but this would fix it if it is really what you have:

```
>>> s='No\xf0\x9f\x92\x80'
>>> len(s)
6
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'No'
```

Instead, if you have literal backslashes and numbers in the string, this would work:

```
>>> s=r'No\xf0\x9f\x92\x80'
>>> s
'No\\xf0\\x9f\\x92\\x80'
>>> len(s)
18
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'No'
```

`unicode-escape` translates escape codes to Unicode code points, but only works on bytes strings.  `.encode('latin1')` translates Unicode code points, 1:1 to their byte equivalent (only works U+0000 to U+00FF, of course).

The code above translates a `str` to `bytes`, decodes the escapes, converts to bytes again, and decodes correctly as UTF-8.

Comment: The second one works. Thank you so much!